# Facing issues while implement threading in this python code, connected with MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

This is the code I wrote to implement threading

```
for i in range(120):
    thread = Thread(target=book, args=(GetUser(i),)).start()
    thread.join()
```

This is how my book function looks like:

```
def book(user): #user -> airline.User, seat -> airline.Seat
    print(user[1] + "with id " + str(user[0]) + " trying to book seat ")
    seats = available_seats()
    print("Total Available seats: " + str(seats[0]))

    #selecting the seat at random
    seat = random.randint(1, seats[0])
    seat = GetSeat(seat)
    print("Seat selected: " + str(seat[1]))
    mycursor.execute("UPDATE seats SET USER_ID = " + str(user[0]) + " WHERE id = " + str(seat[0]))
    mydb.commit()
```

Program work as expected if I wont use threading, but with threading, this is the error I am getting

[image: Error: Lost connection to MySQL server]

This is the complete code, in case you wanted to look at:

```
#In this program Every user is randomly allocated a seat
#without protection the last one to book the seat wins.
#What i am trying to mimic is 120 people coming in at the
#exact same time and all of them assigned 120 seats.

List item

import mysql.connector
import sys
from threading import Thread
import random


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="********",
    password="********",
    database="airline_checkin"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

ALPHA_NUM = {
    "A": 0,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 2,
    "D": 3,
    "E": 4,
    "F": 5,
}

def available_seats():
    mycursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM seats WHERE USER_ID = 0")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        return x

def reset():
    mycursor.execute("UPDATE seats SET USER_ID = 0")
    mydb.commit()


#prints the seats availblity in the plane with "," being available and "X" being booked
def airline():
    seats = [[". " for i in range(20)] for j in range(7)]
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE USER_ID > 0")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        nm = x[1]
        row, c = nm.split("-")
        col = ALPHA_NUM[c]
        seats[col][int(row)-1]= "X "

    for i in range(0, int(len(seats)/2)):
        for j in range(len(seats[i])):
            print(seats[i][j], end="")
        print()

    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(len(seats[i])-1):
            print(" ", end="")
        print()

    for i in range(int(len(seats)/2), len(seats) - 1):
        for j in range(len(seats[i])):
            print(seats[i][j], end="")
        print()


def GetUser(userID):
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " + str(userID))
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        return x

def GetSeat(seatID):

    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE id = " + str(seatID))
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        return x

def book(user): #user -> airline.User, seat -> airline.Seat
    print(user[1] + "with id " + str(user[0]) + " trying to book seat ")
    seats = available_seats()
    print("Total Available seats: " + str(seats[0]))

    #selecting the seat at random
    seat = random.randint(1, seats[0])
    seat = GetSeat(seat)
    print("Seat selected: " + str(seat[1]))
    mycursor.execute("UPDATE seats SET USER_ID = " + str(user[0]) + " WHERE id = " + str(seat[0]))
    mydb.commit()



#Driver Code

reset()

for i in range(120):
    thread = Thread(target=book, args=(GetUser(i),)).start()
    # book(GetUser(i+1))

input("Press enter to continue...")
print()
print("Here is the updated seating chart")
airline()

available_seats()
```

Comment: Database connections are *not* meant to be shared among threads. Even if sharing was possible you'd end up with an unrealistic test. Instead of emulating 120 concurrent connections from 120 different requests, you'd be trying executing 120 commands on a single thread. That would be far *less* likely to lead to blocking, because the database would know the same connection owned the locks from all 120 operations

Comment: BTW the code is full of SQL injection bugs because SQL statements are constructed by concatenating SQL snippets and data. Use parameters instead (not string interpolation, actual parameterized queries). This can *improve* scalability too, because the query is executed just once into an execution plan and that execution plan is reused with different parameter values. When you construct the entire query by concatenating, the server sees a new query every time so it has to compile it again, even if it's almost the same as other queries

Comment: I hope you realize that threads do not literally run simultaneously but rapidly take turns, typically under supervision of the operating system.  Switching of threads can happen between any two Python statements, for example between `my_cursor.execute` and `mydb.commit`.  There is no way that can work reliably.  What you are trying to do here seems like something you shouldn't even be thinking of doing.

Comment: If it is not for production, but **just** for learning multi-threading, SQL injections can be ignored for now. But Paul raises a valid point : this is not a good way to talk to a database, even for learning purposes. You should have a single thread connected to the DB, and then 120 threads that ask it to act on their behalf. It's a bit more difficult to implement.