# Want to simulate booking of 120 users with 120 seats all at once using threading

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to develop a CLI Based application where I want to simulate 120 users books 120 seats all at once.

This is what my program looks like without using Threading, and it is booking the ticket, but its happening in sequential manner

```
import mysql.connector
import concurrent.futures
import sys
from threading import Thread
import random
import asyncio


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="******",
    password="******",
    database="airline_checkin"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

ALPHA_NUM = {
    "A": 0,
    "B": 1,
    "C": 2,
    "D": 3,
    "E": 4,
    "F": 5,
}

def available_seats():
    mycursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM seats WHERE USER_ID = 0")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        return x

def reset():
    mycursor.execute("UPDATE seats SET USER_ID = 0")
    mydb.commit()

def airline():
    seats = [[". " for i in range(20)] for j in range(7)]
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE USER_ID > 0")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        nm = x[1]
        row, c = nm.split("-")
        col = ALPHA_NUM[c]
        seats[col][int(row)-1]= "X "

    for i in range(0, int(len(seats)/2)):
        for j in range(len(seats[i])):
            print(seats[i][j], end="")
        print()

    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(len(seats[i])-1):
            print(" ", end="")
        print()

    for i in range(int(len(seats)/2), len(seats) - 1):
        for j in range(len(seats[i])):
            print(seats[i][j], end="")
        print()


def GetUser(userID):
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " + str(userID))
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        return x

def GetSeat(seatID):
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE id = " + str(seatID))
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        return x

def book(user): #user -> airline.User, seat -> airline.Seat
    print(user[1] + "with id " + str(user[0]) + " trying to book seat ")
    seats = available_seats()
    print("Total Available seats: " + str(seats[0]))

    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE USER_ID = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
        seat = x
        print("Booking the seat: " + seat[1] + " for user: " + user[1])
        #updating the seat
        mycursor.execute("UPDATE seats SET USER_ID = " + str(user[0]) + " WHERE id = " + str(seat[0]))
        mydb.commit()

    print("Transaction got the seat")




#DRIVER CODE
reset()

####### WANT TO MAKE THIS USE MULTIPLE THREADS ########
for i in range(1, 120):
    user = GetUser(i)
    book(user)
####### WANT TO MAKE THIS USE MULTIPLE THREADS ########

input("Press enter to continue...")
print()
print("Here is the updated seating chart")
airline()

available_seats()
```

Output of the program:

[image: Output]

Tried various stuffs to make it use multithreading, but no success yet!!

As of now I just want all 120 users interact with **Seats DB** all at once

This is how DB Structure looks like:

[image: Schema and seats table]

Kindly help me in this :)

Comment: You showed us a non-threaded example and you told us that it works. How about instead, you show us a _threaded_ example that _doesn't_ work, and maybe somebody will be able to help you understand _why_ it doesn't work.

Comment: @SolomonSlow here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74457043/facing-issues-while-implement-threading-in-this-python-code-connected-with-mysq

Comment: @SurajSingh that is not how StackOverflow works. You are expected to post clear questions, showing what is not working. Indeed, in the other question you added threading, but there were different errors. What is the **exact** problem with it ? That's what you should ask. See : [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The more precise the question, the more people answer.